# .conf files comment

Tags: 16.04, configuration, configure

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I think this might be a stupid question to ask. But I wanted to confirm if **#** meant comments in Ubuntu .conf files. For instance in the code below:

```
 #send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
 #send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
 #supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
```

Are all these lines commented out by the .conf file? I ask this because all the lines in the .conf file have a # preceding them. So I am confused if all the lines were meant to be commented.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It depends on what is the conf file. In most cases `#` is a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hashmark in a .conf file is always either an explanatory comment or, in the example you gave, a parameter that may be invoked if it is uncommented.

Many processes run perfectly well with the default settings built in. You may, however, change some settings to better suit your needs by examining the .conf file and invoking the parameter by uncommenting.